# Can I use Ubuntu and its file system on a hard drive?

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, files, external-hdd

I created a bootable USB for Ubuntu as per the instructions [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). My USB was a 500GB external hard drive (NTFS formatted). When I boot Ubuntu, everything works fine, however it asks me whether I want to install Ubuntu onto my laptop. My laptop is managed by my organization and so I cannot do that. What I want to do is have Ubuntu *and* its file system on my hard drive so I can essentially have a portable OS with all of its files to boot from any computer.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### External Hard Drive that Boots on Any Computer

If you want an external hard drive that boots on any computer it must be able to boot in both **BIOS and UEFI** mode.

There are **advantages to a Full install over a Persistent install** see: [I want to make a portable version of Linux Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235480/i-want-to-make-a-portable-version-of-linux-ubuntu/1235490#1235490) . A Full install must be modified to be able to install Ubuntu

A **step by step guide** for creating a Full install USB that can boot both BIOS and UEFI can be found here: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step)

If you just want to **remove the try/install screen** see: [Remove Ubuntu 20.04 Try/Install screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231796/remove-ubuntu-20-04-try-install-screen)

Comment: For the step by step guide, do I need my hard drive *and* a USB? I was thinking I could install it directly onto the HDD, but I really have no experience so it's very likely I'm wrong. If I do need a USB and a hard drive, what size does the USB need to be?

Comment: @applemonkey496 I usually use a 4GB USB 2 Flash drive for installing. You can make the Live USB using: balenaEtcher, Rufus, UNetbootin, YUMI or Ventoy in Windows or mkusb, Startup Disk Creator, MultiBootUSB or Ventoy in Linux.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Unetbootin worked best for me and I got it up and running.