# Error when Installing persistent Ubuntu on USB drive "sdb3 could not be mounted"

Tags: usb, mount, live-usb

i've been trying to install persistent Ubuntu 20.04 on an 16Gb USB 3.1 drive using a non persistent live usb drive with ubuntu 20.04. I've been  following [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) tutorial from how to geek.
Unfortunally somewhere along the process I get this error from mkusb

> /dev/sdb3' could not be mounted.
>
> Poweroff and cold boot for dus-persistent to make persistent live drives again!"

Can someone help me out with this error or tell me a better way to install a persistent ubuntu on a usb drive.

Comment: I have never had **mkusb** fail in such a way, could be bad ISO or faulty mkusb download. If you are up to a small challenge / learning experience, you can make a similar Persistent USB **by hand**: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227221/simple-hand-made-persistent-usb-that-boots-either-bios-or-uefi.