# Make the black screen "Try Xubuntu without installing" appear automatically

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu, lubuntu

I'm making a custom system from Xubuntu (xubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64) using Cubic (Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator) program.

When we turn on the computer with the installation media and press any key, that simple black screen appears with the options "Try Xubuntu without installing" and others.

[image]

How do I leave this behavior as the default? I want this screen to always pop up automatically without the need for user intervention.

In Lubuntu's ISO it's always like this. Which file should I modify to get this?

Comment: Xubuntu uses `ubiquity` and thus has `ubiquity` option at the earlier boot process (ie. `maybe-ubiquity`) which is **not** used by Lubuntu as it doesn't use `ubiquity` instead using `calamares`.  They two are different because they use different installers & thus different options.  You'll also note how it appears differs significantly with the same ISO when booted on BIOS or uEFI firmware (the screen you show I believe is a BIOS display; but 20.04.1 is outdated with changes having occurred since then)

Comment: When booting in BIOS mode Xubuntu uses the Syslinux menu from the txt.cfg file. Pressing the shift key will make the screen in your image appear, (along with the Language menu). When booting in UEFI mode the GRUB menu from grub.cfg normally appears. Boot partitions can be added, (as with mkusb), to enable GRUB booting in BIOS mode also. I do not think that you can boot via the Syslinux txt.cfg menu in UEFI mode.

Comment: I didn't know about these particularities of BIOS and UEFI. Living and learning :D

Answer (score 0):

### Boot Menu every Boot

When booting in BIOS mode Xubuntu uses the Syslinux menu from the txt.cfg file. Pressing the shift key will make the screen in your image appear, (along with the Language menu).

When booting in UEFI mode the GRUB menu from grub.cfg normally appears. Boot partitions can be added, (as with mkusb), to enable GRUB booting in BIOS mode also.

I do not think that you can boot via the Syslinux txt.cfg menu in UEFI mode.

The items on the grub.cfg menu are the same as on the Syslinux txt.cfg menu.

If you would like to boot to the GRUB menu in both BIOS and UEFI modes you can add boot partitions thus:

- Create a GPT partition table.
- Create a 1MB BIOS boot partition 1 on the left, formatted as unformatted.
- Add a 300MB FAT32 EFI boot partition 2 next to it.
- Flag BIOS boot partition `bios_grub`.
- Flag EFI boot partition `boot, esp`
- Copy the boot and EFI folders from the Xubuntu ISO to the EFI boot partition.
- Install grub, if in BIOS mode or booted from USB drive run:

  ```
    sudo mount /dev/sdx2 /mnt

    sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx
  ```

I am not sure how to accomplish the above using Cubic.

Reference: [Simple Hand Made Persistent USB that Boots either BIOS or UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227221/simple-hand-made-persistent-usb-that-boots-either-bios-or-uefi)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!